# Winston timestamps in logfiles and MongoDB is not equal

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, winston

I have a winston logger in my express app which logs entries to logfiles and my MongoDB database. The timestamp for the entries in my logfiles are in the correct local timezone, but the timestamp in MongoDB is automatically set to UTC.

[Log entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBdX6.png)

[Log entries in MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npp0T.png)

Here is my logger module defined in my application

[My winston logger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdN9E.png)

The timezone for the logfile entries was automatically set to UTC to begin with, but when I formatted the entries as such `format: format.combine(format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'}),format.json()),` the logfiles entries were set to my local timezone. How can I update the MongoDB entries to be automatically set to my local timezone?

Comment: Look through mongod configuration options for ones relating to logging.

Comment: mongodb saves date in UTC by default. Check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/